# Jenkins not running TestNG tests via surefire

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

Have a local set up using Maven and TestNG which builds just fine.  The build is a little odd given that in order for the tests to run, a packaged JAR is needed first.  So in effect the local setup runs

```
#!/bin/bash

mvn clean package -Dmaven.test.skip.exec=true
mvn test
```

When run on Jenkins, the clean/package step succeeds as does test, except no tests are actually run:

```
[workspace] $ mvn -f some_sub_directory/pom.xml test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building ...-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ project ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ project ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ project ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ project ---
[INFO] Not compiling test sources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) @ project ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.222s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Nov 22 18:34:00 UTC 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/89M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Seems as though the testCompile and test goals in the surefire plugin aren't finding any test classes.

Is there an additional config needed in pom.xml?

Answer (score 0):

The default and recommended path for test classes is {basedir}/src/test/java/.
But you can precise the path in your pom.xml

```
<build>
   <testSourceDirectory>{basedir}/path/to/test/classes</testSourceDirectory>
    ...
</build>
```

Comment: We did modify the path for source and test files, but those are specified in the pom.xml and like I mentioned, work fine locally.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify your tests that need to be run.  I believe, it looks for tests starting with test*.  If you are using a testng xml then you need to set that up.  Check [this link](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html) out for examples on how to specify tests in different ways.